# How do I change the ":" symbol in the minibuffer?

Tags: command-line

When you switch to command-line-mode, with <kbd>:</kbd>, you see a ":" symbol identifying that you're indeed in command line mode. Is there any way, other than modifying source code, I can change this symbol?

Answer (score 7):

The answer is short and might be unpleasing for you but: no.

You can't change that character without modifying the sources.

Answer (score 0):

I am really not too sure, but by digging through the plugin `vim-easymotion` which displays a prompt "Search for characters: ", I found that it uses:

https://github.com/osyo-manga/vital-over

Which, based on the example, seems to be able to customise the command or search prompt.

I did not have time to experiment deeply with it, but it might be a lead.

Comment: My guess would be that they use a terminal window like fzf-vim for example, where it is easy to change the prompt. However I don't use easymotion and I don't have time to dig the code right now so I could be completely wrong. It's too bad that vital-over doesn't have a complete english documentation by the way.